# How to install a server at home with django&postgre

Tags: django, postgresql, wamp

Please help me to set my home PC as a server (Windows 10 + Python + Django + Postgre SQL + Anaconda)

There are several instructions on how to set the server on the Internet, and surprisingly, many instructions differ from each other. I have absolutely no experience in setting a server. Probably, I’m making a stupid mistake somewhere that I can’t identify for 3 days. I am lost. 
I believe that most useful instructions are these (they are complete and new):
https://www.codementor.io/aswinmurugesh/deploying-a-django-application-in-windows-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-uhl2xq09e
https://ostrokach.gitlab.io/post/apache-django-anaconda/

I followed the instructions and successfully downloaded the necessary modules, installed Wamp, made the changes as displayed in the guide and started it. What I see now: the Wamp icon glows green. When I load a localhost, the page loads endlessly but does not load.

> Wamp error log shows following: [Fri Oct 11 14:50:33.823752 2019]
>   [core:notice] [pid 1364:tid 808] AH00094: Command line:
>   'c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\bin\httpd.exe -d
>   C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.39' [Fri Oct 11 14:50:33.840681 2019]
>   [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1364:tid 808] AH00418: Parent: Created child
>   process 15052 [Fri Oct 11 14:50:34.981629 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice]
>   [pid 15052:tid 800] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

- Project name: turiumasina
- path D:/Users/PycharmProjects/turiumasina/
- path to wsgi:D:/Users/PycharmProjects/turiumasina/turiumasina/wsgi_windows.py  (I renamed wsgi to wsgi_windows, settings file is in turiumasina/turiumasina/)

  1. I copied the output generated by the mod_wsgi-express command and pasted it at the end of C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache\conf\httpd.conf
  2. my httpd-vhosts.conf

ServerName localhost 
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "logs/turiumasina.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/turiumasina.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /      "D:/Users/PycharmProjects/turiumasina/turiumasina/wsgi_windows.py"

```
<Directory "D:/Users/PycharmProjects/turiumasina">
    <Files wsgi_windows.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static "D:/Users/PycharmProjects/turiumasina/static"
<Directory "D:/Users/PycharmProjects/turiumasina/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3. wsgi_windows.py

   ```
   import os
   import sys
   import site
   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


   site.addsitedir("C:/users/.conda/envs/turiumasina/Lib/site-packages")


   sys.path.append('D:/Users/PycharmProjects/turiumasina')

   sys.path.append('D:/Users/PycharmProjects/turiumasina/turiumasina')

   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'turiumasina.settings'
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "turiumasina.settings")

   application = get_wsgi_application()
   ```
4. I generated the "static" folder, wrote a line in the settings.py:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

If I enter `python manage.py runserver` via pycharm, I can see my site through a browser (http://127.0.0.1:8000/). the Wamp icon glows green. When I load a localhost, the page loads endlessly but does not load.

I would like my site to be visible not only to me, but also to Internet users by entering my external IP.

If you need, I can send you the whole project and project settings

Comment: try running the django server using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 & change your firewall settings accordingly if you want it to be exposed externally

Comment: Hello Saawant, thank you for your answer.

Server 0.0.0.0 loaded, I changed the firewall settings, but the site did not appear in the browser. I am investigating this

Comment: Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

When I clicked on this link, I got this error:
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of WAMP altogether, I don't see why you need it if you're not using PHP or MySql.

If you just need to play/debug the Django app over the local network just run ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 (or any other port). Make sure your Windows firewall is allowing incoming connections to the port.

The connect to it you need the computer's actual IP not '0.0.0.0:8000'. Type 'ipconfig' at the command prompt to see what your actual IP is an then connect to Your_actual_IP:8000

If you need something more solid than the build-in Django server (to run in non-debug mode) then you can install Waitress (https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the programs with which I could use my regular home computer as a server to host my site when my PC is enabled? I would like users from the Internet to be able to visit the site if I gave them my IP or domain name with the condition that I would host my site on my own computer with Windows 10? It would be Django + Postgre SQL. I am reading information about waitress. I hope this program will help me to do this

Comment: I found some more information here: https://pypi.org/project/django-webserver/

Comment: pip install django-webserver[waitress]

Comment: In theory you can run django-webserver[waitress] on port 80 if that's what you want, although it's not really a recommended production setup...

Comment: best get an old PC and install a Linux server w. nginx/gunicorn, a good tutorial is here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-apps-using-gunicorn-http-server-behind-nginx